# OpenVPN with VRRP on tap device?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, redundancy

I'm trying to set up HA cluster with OpenVPN tunnel however there's one small problem - whereas VRRP on LAN interface is not a problem, I struggle with VRRP on tap device.

`keepalived` fails to start because tap device after system startup is in `DOWN` state and doesn't have any ip. Thus `keepalived` crashes during startup as it requires some IP to be present on interface in order to get some source IP to send multicast.

If I put static IP on tap interface then `ovpn-server` fails to start as it crashes during ip assignment (because it already exists).

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I'd consider the crashes an actual bug in keepalived, but have you considered changing the startup order (so that keepalived is launched after openvpn)?

Comment: openvpn is "launched" before connection is established. As in if I specify in systemd unit that keepalived should be started after openvpn server it'll start after openvpn starts connection, not after it establishes one. By crashes I mean gentle quit with fail status and appropriate error message.

Comment: This problem should have been fixed in `openvpn-client@.service` in OpenVPN 2.4.

Comment: In your KeepAlived.service you should add WaitFor and Require OpenVPN@client.service , then when your keepalived starts openvpn will be ready, I think you can modify KeepAlived.service and add `ExecPreStart=-script.sh` to ensure tun devices exist .